# opencv_world420.dll not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, darknet

[error shown when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHyUU.png)

I get the above error when running darknet for the first time after building it on windows. How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by copying the **opencv_world420.dll** that you can find in the build folder for opencv where opencv was built and pasting it at the darknet/ root folder.

The precise location of the file opencv_world420.dll will be something like this.
'**C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc16\bin**'
[how the folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W6qm.png)